# Faster alternative to $(window).scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lag

I've noticed that the jQuery scroll bind of $(window).scroll tends to lag down pages a significant amount. For example, I have elements on my page change styles when I scroll past them using the following script:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
     var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
     $('.ElementsToBeChanged').each(function() { 
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                //Add my styles
            }
        });

});
```

It understandably makes the website laggy, since it constantly runs on scroll, but I haven't come across any alternative for triggering events when objects are scrolled past. These kinds of websites that trigger events on scroll seem pretty common; What do they use to bypass this lag?

Comment: A common solution to this is to only execute your code every once in awhile instead of on every `scroll` event.

Comment: Not a full answer, but some things that would help speed this up:
1. Use underscore's debounce. It will only trigger the event if a certain time has elapsed since last invoking it: http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

2. Hold on to object references. Currently, every time you scroll you are querying for the window twice, then you are querying for EVERY element with class "ElementsToBeChanged", then inside of that you are querying for $(this) twice for every "ElementsToBeChanged". You can improve this by the very least pulling your query for "ElementsToBeChanged" outside of the scroll function

Comment: https://johnresig.com/blog/learning-from-twitter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What slows down your performance is not the scroll function itself but the fact that you're doing a lot of calculations per each item on every scroll event.

But despite that I wasn't able to see any drop in performance with 20 elements on screen.

Try to cache your `window` object as variable [ex: `win = $(window)`] and use `el` from the each function instead of `this`.

Instead of changing your css directly using jQuery, try adding/removing classes.

Don't use denounce as others have mentioned as it will not fire until you stop scrolling. What you're looking for is called [throttling](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/).

Here's what I came up with and it works well with 20 elements on my PC:

```js
var win = $(window);

win.scroll(function() {
     var bottom_of_window = win.scrollTop() + win.height();
     $('.ElementsToBeChanged').each(function(index,el) { 
            var bottom_of_object = $(el).offset().top + $(el).outerHeight();
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                $(el).addClass('red');
            }else{
              $(el).removeClass('red');
            }
        });

});
```

```css
.ElementsToBeChanged{
  margin:100px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
  transition:2s;
}

.ElementsToBeChanged.red{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
<div class="ElementsToBeChanged">.ElementsToBeChanged</div>
```

Lastly, just use a plugin such as [Skrollr.js](https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) or [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/)

Comment: Your solution helped the lag a lot - thanks! I've been using velocity.js animations in an attempt to speed up my page - would simply adding classes be faster?

Comment: Glad I could help. Yes. Adding classes and animating using pure CSS will be faster than any plugin. Cheers.